# problem font in ICEpdf viewer when i m transform pdf document in image

Tags: java, icepdf

When i do this in java

```
BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) _document.getPageImage( 0, GraphicsRenderingHints.SCREEN, Page.BOUNDARY_CROPBOX, _rotation, _scale );
```

The ' (apostrophe) in the pdf document become a seven white in a black circle

I'm in 6.2 version of icepdf and i cant upgrade to icepdf 7.0.0 version because our software is not ready to jdk11 yet

But i see the font in my pdf document and it seems to me you support theses fonts already:

Hekvetica: Type: Type1, Encodage: ANSI, Police ArialMT, True Type

Hekvetica-Bold: Type: Type1, Encodage: ANSI, Police Arial-BoldMT, TrueType

Times-Bold: Type: Type1, Encodage: ANSI, Police TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT, True Type

Times-Roman: Type: Type1, Encodage: ANSI, Police TimesNewRomanPSMT, True

It's standard fonts no ?

Thank you for your help

Regards

Didier Maurel

i try to install version 7.0.0
solve this problem